# Raspberry Pi Site Self-Evaluation -- Let's Get Critical!

Tags: discussion

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

**Note:** This evaluation will close on **26 September 2012**. Get your votes in!

Comment: This is an interesting post, thanks Aarthi.

Comment: Anytime! I had great timing, too -- looks like y'all were starting to self-examine anyway. :)

Comment: So, are we forbidden to improve these questions during the voting period?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg You're free to edit/improve any and all questions listed below. :) In fact, we encourage it!

Comment: @Aarthi: I just feared it could result in skewing the outcome of the vote. In case it has any relevance. :)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg No, I say go for it! We can fix/compensate for skew!

Comment: Thanks for all your help, everyone! :D

Answer (score 4):

[How do I set up Pushover service to tell me when my Pi is shutting down or starting up?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1531/how-do-i-set-up-pushover-service-to-tell-me-when-my-pi-is-shutting-down-or-start)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Brilliant question; I learnt a lot about how Linux starts in order to answer this.

Comment: Nice Question, simple answer. Easy to try out!

Answer (score 3):

[How can I generate frequency / pulse signals?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1433/how-can-i-generate-frequency-pulse-signals)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This is a great question, but it is a shame that there is only one answer as there are loads of ways to solve this problem. The OP (@gnibbler) should accept his answer, however.

Answer (score 2):

[Why doesn't my external hard drive appear in /dev?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1415/why-doesnt-my-external-hard-drive-appear-in-dev)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This is a very well answered question. We should clean up the comment stream on the question.

Comment: This question seems very well answered. However it could have some cleaning done to improve the overall quality.

Answer (score 2):

[Do I need to use a ribbon cable for GPIO?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1546/do-i-need-to-use-a-ribbon-cable-for-gpio)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 1):

[How can I change the bash screen resolution to custom values?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1534/how-can-i-change-the-bash-screen-resolution-to-custom-values)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This is a good question, but I think it should be edited to correct the terminology, rather than just a comment.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Go forth and edit. :)

Answer (score 1):

[After writing an SD card image, is the remaining space usable?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1419/after-writing-an-sd-card-image-is-the-remaining-space-usable)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This question and answer is fairly good.

Answer (score 1):

[Custom Raspbian image fails to boot with "no init found"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1474/custom-raspbian-image-fails-to-boot-with-no-init-found)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This is the foundation for a great article on how to build your own image, but as it stands this question isn't very useful.

Comment: This question is asked very well, however the answer is not particuarly useful. I agree with @AlexChamberlain that it could be a good question on how to build your own image.

Comment: I think the answer needs a great deal more information for the question to be useful. It could also be argued that this question is too localized as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

[How can I use an iMac as an external display?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/how-can-i-use-an-imac-as-an-external-display)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I think this is the only question on this list that I don't really like here. We get a **lot** of questions about `X` forwarding, which is probably why that answer was posted, however it doesn't actually answer the question. I think it probably should have been migrated to [Apple.SE] where it could have been answered better.

Answer (score 0):

[How to exit omxplayer without command line?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/how-to-exit-omxplayer-without-command-line)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score -1):

[How do you get wireless LAN working on Raspbmc?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1451/raspbmc-wireless)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Although the question here looks fine, the answers are poor. It would be worth someone else verifying the top answer and providing some sources if the OP isn't going to.

Comment: The uestion could be improved for readability, and the answer is very poor. It would be better suited as a comment.

Comment: @bearbin Feel free to propose edits on posts that you think could be improved, especially where readability is concerned. :)